# Compilation Issue in Nested classes

Tags: c++, templates

```
I am very new to the C++ and i am facing an issue in compiling the following code.
    Some one please help me out .Thanks in Advance.
```

I have added all the template definitions in header files as suggested by members

=====================================================================================
    Test.h
    -------
    #include
    using namespace std;

```
class B;
typedef std::map<B*,int> mymap;
template <class T>
class A
{
  private:
     class B
     {
       public:
       B(T);
       ~B();

       private:
       //some data members
     };
 public:
 A();
 ~A();
 bool add(T);
 bool sort();

 private:
 mymap m_asc_map;
 B* b;
};

template <class T>
A<T>::B::B(T)
{
}
template <class T>
A<T>::B::~B()
{
}
template <class T>
A<T>::A()
{
}
template <class T>
A<T>::~A()
{
}

template <class T>
bool A<T>:: add(T x)
{
  b = new B(x);
  return true;
}
template <class T>
bool A<T>:: sort()
{
   m_asc_map.insert(std::make_pair(b,1));
  return true;
}

Test.cc
-------

#include "Test.h"

int main()
{
  A<int> a;
  a.add(10);
  a.sort();
  return 0;
}

=====================================================================================
I am getting the following error

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_pair.h: In constructor â€˜std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_U1, _U2>&) [with _U1 = A<int>::B*, _U2 = int, _T1 = B* const, _T2 = int]â€™:
Test.h:56:   instantiated from â€˜bool A<T>::sort() [with T = int]â€™
Test.cc:7:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_pair.h:90: error: cannot convert â€˜A<int>::B* constâ€™ to â€˜B* constâ€™ in initialization
```

Comment: Can you please copy the complete error message including the line number and the line containing the error? Also your files seem to be incomplete, you never include the header.

Answer (score 0):

You forward declare class B (`class B;`) but provide no definition for it. (Obviously, you declare later another `class B` in the A, but please note, that `::B` (the `B` you declare in the global namespace) is not `A::B` (the `B` you declare in the class)

Also, it's `private`, not `Private`. And if you work with templates, put all the method definitions in the header file, otherwise you will get a lot more errors.

Also, `std::map<B*,int> mymap;` declares a global variable, not a type, so you cannot use it later like: `mymap m_asc_map;`. Try to do a "proper" `typedef` :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because you put the template definitions in *.cc file. It is recommended to put all template definitions in *.h files.